# how babel-loader deal with ES6 import?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Does babel-loader just leave the import tasks to webpack? Any difference between babel-loader in webpack and the babel tool alone in node CLI?

Answer (score 0):

They're about the same, I think they both use the same babel-core for trans-piling.  Using babel loader ensures that webpack runs matched files through babel before concatenating them (or whatever else). I think your es6 import statements will be transpiled to requires and then followed by webpack. Most babel CLI options should be available to webpack loader. Here's a config example:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loaders: ['json-loader']
        }
        , {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                optional: ['es7.classProperties']
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

[webpack loader docs.](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html)